# /var/mqm folder is getting overwritten with PV in kubernetes deployment of ACE-MQ with ibmcom/ace-mq image

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-mq

Trying to deploy MQ with AppConnect in AWS Cloud with EFS as persistence storage for a HA solution. While trying to deploy with keeping /var/mqm (tried with mnt/mqm also) in the mount path, it is getting overwritten with the blank Persistence storage data. So when pod is up, I can't see the queue manager or other files inside /var/mqm.

This is the deployment.yml used

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  generation: 1
  labels: 
    run: acemq01
  name: acemq01
  namespace: default
spec: 
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      run: acemq01
  strategy: 
    rollingUpdate: 
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template: 
    metadata: 
      creationTimestamp: ~
      labels: 
        run: acemq01
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          env: 
            - 
              name: LICENSE
              value: accept
            - 
              name: DOMAIN
              value: cluster
            - 
              name: MQ_QMGR_NAME
              value: MQAWS
          image: ibmcom/ace-mq
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: acemq01
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          volumeMounts: 
            - 
              mountPath: /var/mqm
              name: pv-volumeef
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes: 
        - 
          name: pv-volumeef
          persistentVolumeClaim: 
            claimName: efs
status: {}
```

Comment: Can you include also PVC and `StorageClass` resource definitions into the question?